# How To Join AVI Files Without Reencoding Them?

Tags: software-recommendation, video

I have several avi-containers with exactly same type of content, framerate, bitrate and encoding match as they are coming from a camera that splitted the files.
Currently I'm using [D-Vision](http://www.objectifmac.com/dvision.php) but its development stopped and starting with Lion it tends to break the files which then have to be remuxed to fastforward properly.

Do you have any software recommendations for me? It MUST NOT reencode the streams!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I get 100% what you want, so correct me if I'm wrong...

You can just use QuickTime (7 Pro or X -> I'm not sure about QT X). Just copy/paste the several files in one new window and export to .avi. It takes some time to export them, but you are not re-encoding them...

**EDIT:**
Try downloading [this plugin](http://www.xvid.org/Software.83.0.html) for playing Xvid-files with QuickTime.

Comment: Does this work even if QT can isn't aware of the codecs in use?

Comment: So you can't open the files using QT?

Comment: It shows 00:00 playing time.

Comment: That's not good. Which extension are you trying to open? Or even better, do you know the codec?

Comment: It's XVID, NTSC framerate, 16:9 in an avi-container. I don't have perian installed

Comment: You don't need Perian for Xvid. Just a extra plugin. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Often you can just use Terminals.app's [`cat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/cat.1.html) [command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/cat.1.html) to join AVI files without re-encoding.

Try opening terminal.app, and entering:

> `cat` *path_to_part_one.avi* *path_to_part_two.avi* `>` *name_for_the_joined file.avi*

You may also need to rebuild the AVI index, DTBaker has a [good tutorial](http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/join-multiple-avi-files.html).

Comment: If you use cat to join AVI files, the result will have an invalid index. Instructions to rebuild it are at http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/join-multiple-avi-files.html.

Comment: Good point! I'll edit your link in.